# How to trigger a event when user press done button in keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I want to trigger an event when the user clicks done button in android keyboard

For Example: In login activity when I enter the password and press done button at right bottom corner of keyboard it close the keyboard and then I press the login button. Instead of that when the user press done button in keyboard the authentication should happen.

Comment: Post the code if you are looking for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```